# I don't know how to draw a picture like this.

Tags: diagrams

I want to draw a picture like below.
[image]
But I don't know where I should start with. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No offense but why would you draw this? What do the dotted lines represent? why broken arrows? Why colors? I'm sure you can better represent this information in a more concise manner.

Comment: @percusse I'm just asking this question for other person. The picture I received is exactly this one, which contains dotted lines, broken arrows, and red equation on the bottom-right.

Comment: Can you give us some code that you have tried? What, specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: @darthbith I don't have code. Actually, I don't know where to get start.

Comment: @OldPanda Do you have a `\documentclass` and a preamble? Every little bit helps... look at a tutorial for TikZ to get started

Comment: @darthbith Thank you! I'll refer to a tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a starting point.  `zz` arrow style is defined in `zz` whose zigzag form is borrowed from `decoration`. `positioning` are used for node allocations where the syntax `below = <distance> of reference point` are used. `calc` is used to do coordinate calculation as displayed in ($(...)+(...)$).

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,positioning}
\tikzset{zz/.style={thick,->,
line join=round,
decorate, decoration={
    zigzag,
    segment length=4,
    amplitude=2,post=lineto,
    post length=4pt}
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (top) at (0,0) {$\mathbf{v}_{\text{init}},\epsilon$};
\node[below= 1cm of top](mid)    {$\mathbf{v},\sigma$};
\node[below= 1cm of mid](bottom) {$\mathbf{v}',\sigma'$};
\node[below=3cm of top](bb){};
\draw[zz] (top) -- (mid);
\draw[zz] (mid) -- node[midway,red,left]{$(\mathbf{u},\rho)$} (bottom);
\draw [red,thick]($(bb)+(-0.5cm,0)$)-- ($(bb)+(0.5cm,0)$) node[text width=5cm,right]()
{if $
\begin{cases}
\mathbf{v} \le \mathbf{v}'\\
\sigma \le_{\text{prefix}} \rho\,\, \text{for all}\, (\mathbf{u},\rho)
\end{cases}
$};
\draw[dashed] (top) -- ++(-3,-3);
\draw[dashed] (top) -- ++(3,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```